# How to set Title Bar Text and Application Icon

Tags: qb64

I want to make my QB64 program look professional, by setting a custom text in the Title Bar rather than the default (file name) and a custom Icon for the application file to be displayed in the Taskbar and Title Bar.

I tried to use Resource Hacker but couldn't change the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following code at the top of your program:

```
$EXEICON = 'path/to/icon-image'
_TITLE "Title Bar Text"
```

***Note:*** The icon image must be in `.ico` format and the path should be correct, or else the program won't compile!

Answer (score 0):

Some old version of QB64 required an additional variable to declare icon:

```
$EXEICON = 'path/to/icon-image'
_ICON
```

and won't add the icon otherwise.